# Fetch date and time of last activity by any Android app

Tags: applications

I am trying to find the last used time of an Android application.

`UsageStats` is the way, but prior to Android Lollipop, this information is not accessible programmatically. Please suggest to me some way if it is possible to access `UsageStats` for the version below Lollipop.

What I tried to get the last used is the access date and time of the folder generated by apps in `/sdcard/Android/data/pkg_name`, but the problem is not all the apps make this kind of `data` folder.

Is there any other possibility to access the date and time of the applications?

Comment: Note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues. While the community may provide answers using tools generally used by power users like `adb` or `shell`, code that calling Android API is generally off-topic if end-users can't call it directly from the phone/PC.

Answer (score 0):

One can access the last modified date of `/data/data/{package_name}` programmatically. The directory structure inside `{package_name}` is not visible in a non-rooted device, but the last modified date of the `{package_name}` folder can give an approximation when the user last access an app.

[image]